# Angular Js Link to Partial Pages

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an single page mobile web app using angular.

First time i will load the `partial-For-routes-1.html`, then from that i want to go to `partial-For-routes-2.html` and `partial-For-routes-3.html` by using the links, how do i give links to the page-2 and page-3, is it better to use `href` as i used below or better to use `ng-href`?

In normal desktop web apps, we could just use the relative path of the page to be loaded in `href` attribute. i don't know how to do that in angular js framework with partials. please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Please correct me that i used correct syntax to link to the partials.

**`Index.html`**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My HTML File</title>
        <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/routes.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
        <div class="" ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`app.js`**

```
    angular.module('myApp', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
                    when('/', 
                        {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/partial-For-routes-1.html', 
                        controller: appCtrl
                        }).
                    when('/page-2', 
                        {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/partial-For-routes-2.html', 
                        controller: appCtrl
                        }).
                    when('/page-3', 
                        {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/partial-For-routes-3.html', 
                        controller: appCtrl
                        }).
                    otherwise({redirectTo:("/")})
     }]);
```

**`partial-For-routes-1.html`**

```
<p>Total number of phones: 1</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 1</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 1</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 1</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 1</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 1</p>
<p><a href="#/page-2" class="">Go to Page 2</a></p>
<p><a href="#/page-3" class="">Go to Page 3</a></p>
```

**`partial-For-routes-2.html`**

```
<p>Total number of phones: 2</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 2</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 2</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 2</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 2</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 2</p>
<p><a href="#/page-1" class="">Go to Page 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#/page-3" class="">Go to Page 3</a></p>
```

**`partial-For-routes-3.html`**

```
<p>Total number of phones: 3</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 3</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 3</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 3</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 3</p>
<p>Total number of phones: 3</p>
<p><a href="#/page-1" class="">Go to Page 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#/page-2" class="">Go to Page 2</a></p>
```

Comment: its absolutely fine to use href tag and in html just use #/page-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
  .when('/page/:id', 
  {
    templateUrl: 'partials/partial-For-routes.html', 
    controller: appCtrl
  })
```

You can also do the routing like this and it works the same:

```
 .when('/page-:id', 
  {
    templateUrl: 'partials/partial-For-routes.html', 
    controller: appCtrl
  })
```

and inside your appCtrl you would read the route value to determine the page.. This allows you to handle all paging inside one controller with one view.

In your controller this will be available so you can handle the paging:  `$routeParams.id` based on a dynamic route value.

Your links would be `href='#/page/1'` or per your note, they can be like this `href='#/page-1'` depending on how you define your rule.

Here is a demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/a2qaF0rAAgI5UMCY6RcO?p=preview

Here is the full screen link if you want to see the route changes better:  http://plnkr.co/a2qaF0rAAgI5UMCY6RcO

Comment: Thanks For the answer what i am expecting: is it okay to use like href="#/page-1" to make the user to see the partial page 1 if click that link and so on.

Comment: You can absolutely do your routing like that.. Check out the demo I just added.